# Querying TableItem's data object (SWT)

Tags: java, swt

I have a table `featuresTable` of type `Table`.

I'm able to do the following to retrieve the first item (assume here that there always is one):

```
TableItem item = featuresTable.getItem(0);
```

That's all good.

What I want to do now is to get its data:

```
Object data = item.getData();
```

The problem is that I want access to some of the fields of that data object. E.g. `data.requirements`, but there is no getter available.

How do I access all the fields of the data object? I know that `data.requirements` is there because when debugging I can see it, but the fields are not available to me through my own code. Obviously this makes sense but since there is no getter, I can't figure out how to retrieve it since I can't modify the code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get from the item? The text in a cell? `data` is of type `Object`. You'd need to cast it to the data type you used when you called `item.setData()`.

Comment: @Baz I should spend some more time reading the actual API... It's not my code so I didn't even look to see that it used `setData()` and that I could retrieve this by `getData(key)`. Solved the problem! If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it since you were right about `setData()` and then just casting it when invoking `getData()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the code you're using utilizes `Widget#setData(String, Object)`.
In order to get your data back, you can use `Widget#getData(String)`.

If the original data was of type `A`, you'd also need to cast it back:

```
A myData = (A) item.getData("myKey");
```